# php signup form doesn't carry out the password length check correctly

Tags: php, html, validation

I am trying to carry out some validation checks on a user signup form using HTML and PHP. I have tried to add in one which checks the character length of the username that's been inputted. When I run the script I do hit the correct URL error: `http://localhost:8888/PRCO304/signup.php?error=invalidlengthuname=ttttttt` however I do not get the html message that should be returned to the signup.php page to the user. `Which should be: **"Username must be at least 8 characters long!"**

**scripts/signup-script.php:**

```
<?php
// Checking whether the user got to this page by clicking the proper signup button.
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

  require 'db.php';

  $firstName = $_POST['first-name'];
  $lastName = $_POST['last-name'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];


  // We check for any empty inputs. 
  if (empty($firstName) || empty($lastName) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uname=".$username."&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  // We check for an invalid username AND invalid e-mail.
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidunamemail");
    exit();
  }
  // We check for an invalid username. In this case ONLY letters and numbers.
  else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduname&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  // We check for minimum amount of characters in username.
  else if (strlen($username <= 7)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidlengthuname=".$username);
    exit();
  }
  // We check for an invalid e-mail.
  else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&uname=".$username);
    exit();
  }
  // We check if the repeated password is NOT the same.
  else if ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&uname=".$username."&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  else {

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM student WHERE username = ?;";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      // If there is an error we send the user back to the signup page.
      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }
    else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
      // Then we execute the prepared statement and send it to the database!
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      // Then we store the result from the statement.
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
      // Then we get the number of result we received from our statement. This tells us whether the username already exists or not!
      $resultCount = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
      // Then we close the prepared statement!
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      // Here we check if the username exists.
      if ($resultCount > 0) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?error=usertaken&mail=".$email);
        exit();
      }
      else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO student (firstName, lastName, username, email, pwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
        // Here we initialize a new statement using the connection from the db.php file.
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        // Then we prepare our SQL statement AND check if there are any errors with it.
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
          // If there is an error we send the user back to the signup page.
          header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
          exit();
        }
        else {

          // If there is no error then we continue the script!

          $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $firstName, $lastName, $username, $email, $hashedPwd);

          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

          header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
          exit();

        }
      }
    }
  }

  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
else {
  // If the user tries to access this page an inproper way, we send them back to the signup page.
  header("Location: ../signup.php");
  exit();
}
```

**signup.php:**

```
<?php
    // The index homepage includes the header
    require 'header.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- CSS STYLING --> 
    <link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- The start of my Foldy Grids -->
    <section id="content">
            <div class="container">
                <section id="grid" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="cf show-grid">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="grid-1">grid-1</div>
                        <div class="grid-4">
            <?php

                // Here we create an error messages if the user made an error trying to sign up.
                if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
                if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyfields") {
                    echo '<p class="signuperror">Fill in all fields!</p>';
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "invalidunamedmail") {
                    echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid username and email!</p>';
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "invaliduname") {
                    echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid username!</p>';
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "invalidmail") {
                    echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid email!</p>';
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "passwordcheck") {
                    echo '<p class="signuperror">Your passwords do not match!</p>';
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "usertaken") {
                    echo '<p class="signuperror">Username is already taken!</p>';
                }
                else if ($_GET["error"] == "invalidlengthuname") {
                    echo '<p class="signuperror">Username must be at least 8 characters long!</p>';
                }
                }
                // Here we create a success message if the new user was created.
                else if (isset($_GET["signup"])) {
                if ($_GET["signup"] == "success") {
                    echo '<p class="signupsuccess">Signup successful!</p>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
                        <form action="scripts/signup-script.php" method="post">

                            <div class="signupContainer">
                                <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                                <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
                                <hr>
                            <?php
                                if (!empty($_GET["first-name"])) {
                                    echo '<label for="first-name"><b>First Name</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first-name" value="'.$_GET["first-name"].'">';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<label for="first-name"><b>First Name</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first-name">';
                                }
                                if (!empty($_GET["last-name"])) {
                                    echo '<label for="last-name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last-name" value="'.$_GET["last-name"].'">';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<label for="last-name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Last Name" name="last-name">';
                                }
                                if (!empty($_GET["username"])) {
                                    echo '<label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="'.$_GET["username"].'">';
                                } else{
                                    echo '<label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">';
                                }
                                if (!empty($_GET["email"])) {
                                    echo '<label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="'.$_GET["email"].'">';
                                } else {
                                    echo '<label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">';
                                }
                            ?>
                                <label for="pwd"><b>Password</b></label>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd">

                                <label for="pwd-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="pwd-repeat">

                                <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
                                </label>

                                <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

                                <div class="clearfix">
                                <button type="submit" class="signupBtn" name="signup-submit">Sign Up</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>

                        </div>
                        <div class="grid-1">grid-1</div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- The end of my Foldy Grids above -->
    </body>

    </html>
    <?php
        require 'footer.php';
    ?>
```

Comment: Change `if (strlen($username <= 7)) {` to `if (strlen($username <  7)) {` then change else if statement to if statement.

Comment: Hi @Dlk I tried to make the change, re-run it however the correct message still does not appear to the user on the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple in my point of view:

In the URL you are expecting the `error` parameter to return `invalidlengthuname`

Meaning `$_GET['error'] = 'invalidlengthuname'`, though as I see in your example and in your redirection, the `$_GET['error']` is equal to `invalidlengthuname=ttttttt`.

You should remove the second `=` along with the "ttttttt" or create a second URL parameter so you can track which username the user has posted: `?error=invalidlengthuname&input=ttttttt`. Note the `&` sign.

Answer (score 2):

Corrected `if (strlen($username < 7)) {` you might need to put ! (not) in front of strlen.

To me your codes should look like this.

**UPDATE** had to specify second parameter in url `&uname=` and correct some double checks in your codes and tested its working fine:

```
$error '';
if (isset($_POST['signup-submit'])) {

  require 'db.php';

  $firstName = $_POST['first-name'];
  $lastName = $_POST['last-name'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $password = $_POST['pwd'];
  $passwordRepeat = $_POST['pwd-repeat'];


  // We check for any empty inputs. 
  if (empty($firstName) || empty($lastName) || empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password) || empty($passwordRepeat)) {
    $error = 'error';
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfields&uname=".$username."&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  // We check for an invalid username. In this case ONLY letters and numbers.
  if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username)) {
    $error = 'error';
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invaliduname&uname=".$username);
    exit();
  }
  // We check for minimum amount of characters in username.
  if(strlen($username) < 8){
    $error = 'error';
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=lenuname&uname=".$username);
    exit();
  }
  // We check for an invalid e-mail.
  if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error = 'error';
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidmail&mail=".$email);
    exit();
  }
  // We check if the repeated password is NOT the same.
  if ($password !== $passwordRepeat) {
    $error = 'error';
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=passwordcheck&password=".$passwordRepeat);
    exit();
  }
  if(empty($error)){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student (firstName, lastName, username, email, pwd) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);";
    // Here we initialize a new statement using the connection from the db.php file.
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    // Then we prepare our SQL statement AND check if there are any errors with it.
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      // If there is an error we send the user back to the signup page.
      header("Location: ../signup.php?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }else {

      // If there is no error then we continue the script!

      $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $firstName, $lastName, $username, $email, $hashedPwd);

      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

      header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=success");
      exit();

    }
  }
}
```

Your `signup.php`

```
<?php

    // Here we create an error messages if the user made an error trying to sign up.
    if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
        if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyfields") {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Fill in all fields!</p>';
        }
        if ($_GET["error"] == "invalidunamedmail") {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid username and email!</p>';
        }
        if ($_GET["error"] == "invaliduname") {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid username!</p>';
        }
        if ($_GET["error"] == "invalidmail") {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Invalid email!</p>';
        }
        if ($_GET["error"] == "passwordcheck") {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Your passwords do not match!</p>';
        }
        if ($_GET["error"] == "usertaken") {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Username is already taken!</p>';
        }
        if ($_GET["error"] == "lenuname") {
            echo '<p class="signuperror">Username must be at least 8 characters long!</p>';
        }
    }
    // Here we create a success message if the new user was created.
    if (isset($_GET["signup"])) {
        if ($_GET["signup"] == "success") {
            echo '<p class="signupsuccess">Signup successful!</p>';
            }
    }
?>
<form action="scripts/signup-script.php" method="post">

    <div class="signupContainer">
        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
        <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
        <hr>
    <?php
        if (!empty($_GET["first-name"])) {
            echo '<label for="first-name"><b>First Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first-name" value="'.$_GET["first-name"].'">';
        } else {
            echo '<label for="first-name"><b>First Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first-name">';
        }
        if (!empty($_GET["last-name"])) {
            echo '<label for="last-name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last-name" value="'.$_GET["last-name"].'">';
        } else {
            echo '<label for="last-name"><b>Last Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Please Enter Last Name" name="last-name">';
        }
        if (!empty($_GET["username"])) {
            echo '<label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="'.$_GET["username"].'">';
        } else{
            echo '<label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username">';
        }
        if (!empty($_GET["email"])) {
            echo '<label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="'.$_GET["email"].'">';
        } else {
            echo '<label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">';
        }
    ?>
        <label for="pwd"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd">

        <label for="pwd-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="pwd-repeat">

        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
        </label>

        <p>By creating an account you agree to our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a>.</p>

        <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" class="signupBtn" name="signup-submit">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

See screenshot

[image]

Comment: `if(strlen(trim($username)) < 7){` should be `if(strlen($username) < 8){` cause 1. His error message is: **Username must be at least 8 characters long!** 2. He already check before that the username can only contains numbers and letters (white-space isn't defined in the pattern!)

Comment: OP is checking for 7 characters, no meter what you print in explanition not makes sense, probably `else if` causing problem, this is a tutorial from mmtuts, I used this tutorial for a demo, was checking for password length `if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
  header("location: login.php?error=PassLength");
  exit();
    }`

Comment: Then you should ask the OP if he want to check for a length of 8 or 7. And the trim didn't made sense in your check (reason I've explained in my comment before).

Comment: Question is about **however I do not get the html message that should be returned to the signup.php** not about username **length** dont comment about codes if you dont have an idea like in your first comment. and I bet OP has enough knowledge to change length from 7 to 8

Comment: Hi both, sorry yeah that 7 was a simple typo from me. Also yes this is a based on an mmtuts tutorial, however regardless of whether I place a `!` before the `strlen(trim($username)) < 8) {` I still get the correct URL error, but not the actual error message in html on the front end?

Comment: Interesting I tested the codes its not displaying only for that field strange :)

Comment: @K.Haydock see updated answer I corrected its working fine on my local now.

Comment: @Dlk Hey :) Can I asked what you changed in order for it to work?

Comment: @K.Haydock I explained in answer! specified second parameter in url `&uname=` Changed url like this `header("Location: ../signup.php?error=lenuname&uname=".$username);` and in signup `if ($_GET["error"] == "lenuname") { echo '<p class="signuperror">Username must be at least 8 characters long!</p>'; }` And corrected double checks and some wrong variables, I didnt include part of the codes where you check for username and email, you can add that in my answer. Try to compare my codes and yours you can see the differences

Comment: I removed all else statements in both files, and removed double checks  `else if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?error=invalidunamemail");
    exit();
  }` which you didnt need, you already check once, and changed some more things.

Comment: In this statement `if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {` if you wanna check for double values you need to change `&&` to `||`,  I corrected some things cant remember all :)